# Change font size in minted

Tags: minted

i'have this in my document

```
\begin{minted}{objc}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
\end{minted}
```

But I would like to reduce the size of the text '@property ..' because it is very long and I do not want it to head..
I do not understand how to change the size of font :\

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a compilable example. Have you tried the standard LaTeX commands for font sizes?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`minted` has a `fontsize` option.

Here some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\noindent This is \verb|\footnotesize|:
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\footnotesize]{objc}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
\end{minted}
This is \verb|\small|:
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\small]{objc}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
\end{minted}
This is a normal text size for comparison:
\begin{minted}{objc}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to change overall font size https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484788/how-to-change-overall-font-size-of-minted?